# If no optional parameter supplied, shouldn't it use default?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have the following:

```
void MyMethod(ClassA classa, bool useWhite=true)
{...}
```

If I call

```
MyMethod(myclassA);
```

shouldn't useWhite be true inside of MyMethod()?  I'm finding that in the above case, it is false.

Comment: It _is_ true, so show code that is reproducable. http://ideone.com/YwsQ64

Comment: Can you post a compilable example?

Comment: Is it possible you have a field named `useWhite` that's initialized to false instead?

Comment: I can't post an example because of the workflow required to reach this point.  It is using an interface that has the optional param.  Does that affect anything?  Nothing else is using useWhite.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it's not to do with this default parameter.  Look elsewhere...

Comment: Well it's hard to tell exactly what's going on without seeing more code. It definitely *should* be `true`, based solely on what you've shown, which suggests the real issue is somewhere else.

Comment: pause the debugger just before, and again inside of your method. Maybe you have a side effect, maybe you have a typo?

Comment: Here's a new one for you - I changed it from a bool to an int with default =1.  When I step into the method, it is zero.  Really not sure what the point of having defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the cause can be that your class implements an interface and that the interface defines a different default value for the parameter, e.g. `useWhite = false`.

The following example will output "False":

```
public interface I
{
    void Test(bool b = false);
}
public class C : I
{
    public void Test(bool b = true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    I i = new C();
    i.Test();       // <-- prints "False"
    new C().Test(); // <-- prints "True"
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That isn't the case here.

Comment: @4thSpace Unless you provide actual code that demonstrates the issue, guesses are all you're going to get.